# Не считывается вся цепь графа с файла и не выводится

Tags: c++

Есть 2 класса матричных изображений графа:
1)Через динамический массив динамических массивов.
2)Через вектор векторов.
В обоих есть проблемы. В первом не считывается до конца цепь графа длиною 50000. На ~42тыс кидает исключение доступа по адресу. И кидает всегда на разном элементе(42 254 или 42 258 и т.д.)
Во втором классе файл считывается быстро, но очень долго выводит(порядка нескольких минут)
Минимальный нужный пример:
`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <forward_list>

using namespace std;

class VList {
public:
    VList() = delete;
    VList(int);
    VList(const VList&) = delete;
    VList(VList&&);
    ~VList();
    void add(int v); // додати вершину
    bool notEmpty();
    // чи не порожній список
    void output(std::ofstream& f);
    // вивести вершини списку
protected:
    int nmax, n;
    int* vList;
};


class GrA { // абстрактний клас
public:
    GrA();
    int getN()
    {
        return n;
    }
    int getM()
    {
        return m;
    }
    bool getIsDir()
    {
        return isDir;
    }
    void setIsDir(bool d)
    {
        isDir = d;
    }
    virtual bool create(int n) = 0;
    virtual bool addArc(int, int) = 0;
    virtual VList neighbors(int v) = 0;
protected:
    bool isDir = false;
    int n = 0, m = 0;
};

class GrMA : public GrA {
public:
    bool create(int n);
    bool addArc(int, int);
    VList neighbors(int v);
    void dispose();
    ~GrMA();
protected:
    bool** E;
};

class GrMV : public GrA
{
public:
    bool create(int n);
    bool addArc(int, int);
    VList neighbors(int v);
    ~GrMV();
protected:
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> vc;
};



string GetPath();
bool input(string path, GrA& g);
bool output(string path, GrA& g);
void process(GrA& gr, time_t& t_in, time_t& t_out);

int main()
{
    time_t t_in,t_out;
    GrMA gr1;
    GrMV gr2;


    process(gr1, t_in, t_out);
    cout << "GraphMatrix3"<<endl<<"t_in: " << t_in/1000 << "sec" <<t_in%1000<<"ms"<< endl
         <<"t_out: " << t_out/1000<< "sec" << t_in%1000<<"ms"<< endl;
    process(gr2, t_in, t_out);
    cout << "GraphMatrix5" << endl <<"t_in: " << t_in/1000 << "sec" <<t_in%1000<<"ms"<< endl
         <<"t_out: " << t_out/1000<< "sec" << t_in%1000<<"ms"<< endl;
}

void process(GrA& gr, time_t& t_in, time_t& t_out)
{
    string path;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter path to infile: " << endl;
        path = GetPath();
        t_in = clock();
        if (input(path, gr))
        {
            t_in = (clock() - t_in);
            break;
        }
    } while (true);

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter path to outfile: " << endl;
        path = GetPath();
        t_out = clock();
        if (output(path, gr))
        {
            t_out = (clock() - t_out) ;
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
}



bool input(string path, GrA& g)
{
    ifstream s;
    s.open(path);
    if (!s)
    {
        s.clear();
        return false;
    }
    int i, j, isDir, n;
    s >> isDir >> n;
    g.setIsDir(isDir);
    if (!(g.create(n)))
        return false;
    while (s >> i >> j)
        g.addArc(i, j);
    s.close();
    return true;
}

bool output(string path, GrA& g)
{
    ofstream f(path);
    if (!f)
    {
        f.clear();
        return false;
    }
    int n = g.getN(), m = g.getM(), d = g.getIsDir();
    f << d << ' ' << n << ' ' << m << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        VList nbs = g.neighbors(i);
        f << i << ": ";
        nbs.output(f);
        f << endl;
    }
    f.close();
    return true;
}


string GetPath()
{
    string path;
    getline(cin, path, '\n');
    return path;
}
VList::VList(int _n) : vList(new int[_n]), nmax(_n), n(0) {}
VList::VList(VList&& r) : vList(r.vList), nmax(r.nmax), n(r.n) {
    r.vList = nullptr; r.nmax = 0; r.n = 0;
}
VList::~VList() {
    delete[] vList;
}
void VList::add(int v) {
    if (n < nmax) vList[n++] = v;   // додавання в кінці списку
}
bool VList::notEmpty() {
    return n > 0;
}
void VList::output(ofstream& f)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        f << vList[i] << ' ';
}

GrA::GrA() {};

bool GrMA::create(int _n)
{
    if (E != nullptr)
    {
        dispose();
    }
    E = new(nothrow) bool*[_n]{};
    if (E != nullptr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _n; i++)
        {
            E[i] = new(nothrow) bool[_n] {};
        }
        n = _n;
    }
    return (E != nullptr);
}

bool GrMA::addArc(int v, int w) {
    E[v][w] = true;
    if (!isDir)
        E[w][v] = true;
    ++m;
    return true;
}

VList GrMA::neighbors(int k) {
    VList L(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (E[k][i])
            L.add(i);
    return L;
}
void GrMA::dispose() //
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete[] E[i];
    delete[] E;
    E = nullptr;
    n = m = 0;
}
GrMA::~GrMA()
{
    dispose();
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool GrMV::create(int _n)
{
    if (vc.size() != 0)
        vc.clear();
    vc.resize(_n);
    for (int i = 0; i < _n; i++)
    {
        vc.at(i).resize(_n);
    }
    n = _n;
    return true;
}

bool GrMV::addArc(int v, int w)
{
    vc.at(v).at(w) = true;
    if (!isDir)
        vc.at(w).at(v) = true;
    ++m;
    return true;
}

VList GrMV::neighbors(int k)
{
    VList L(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (vc.at(k).at(i))
            L.add(i);
    return L;
}

GrMV::~GrMV()
{};
```

Код для создания файла с цепью:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path = "in_50000.txt";
    ofstream f;
    f.open(path);
    const int LEN=50000;
    f << 0 << " " << LEN << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN-1; i++)
    {
        f << i << " " << i + 1 << endl;
    }
    f.close();
}
```

Comment: Не, без мейна понять что у тебя нетак неполучится. А в VList нехватает ещё  2 орераторов равенства.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков , Так мейн же есть, перед функцией process

Comment: Итого 2.5 миллиарда записей. Надо не более `unsigned char`, чтоб хотя бы втиснуться в 2.5 Гбайта. Если граф неориентированный - достаточно хранить только его половину. Если граф разреженный (ваш случай) - хранить не матрицей, а списком смежности, например.

Comment: @Harry У меня в проекте у меня всего 4 класса графов(2 матрицы и 2  списка и списки работают отлично). Ну вот проблема в том, что мне обязательно надо чтобы эти 2 матрицы работали(Задание лабораторной), а как пофиксить ума не приложу

Comment: Тупо "в лоб" - массив `unsigned char` и масса памяти. Или даже реализовать хранение в одном  `unsigned char` 8 значений. Получится порядка 300 мегабайт, мелочи :) Если можно хитро - смотреть "[разреженные матрицы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)". Можно реализовать через те же списки, раз у вас С++, с "матричным" интерфейсом - внешне будет выглядеть как работа с матрицей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё норм вроде, работает.
Компилить на x64. Надо 10 ГБ оперативки.

А долго потому что

1. vector ест 1 бит а массив инт 32 бита в 32 раза больше памяти прерлопатить.
2. 50000 элементов массив временный хавает немало.

Comment: Во-первых, у меня дольше работает вектор векторов. А во-вторых У меня же массив bool, который  ест аналогично памяти, как и вектор bool. Могу ошибаться

Comment: new int[_n]

но даже если bool, то серавно в 8 раз больше памяти. Так как размер bool 8 бит.
У меня оно не крашилось, точнее не скажу.

Comment: `vector<bool>` места занимает меньше, а вот работает дольше, потому что упаковывает каждый `bool` в один бит - вот время на упаковку-распаковку и требуется.

Comment: @Mikhailo, Поменял на вектор чаров в пользу времени, теперь работает так, как планировалось. Спасибо